# Is it possible to pass GET response data back to same factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, get, factory

### Question:

**From any controller, how can I call the `getPages` function, return the data back to the controller and  replace the empty `Page.details.ref`object with the `GET` response data?**

**is it possible for this all to happen within the factory regardless of which controller calls the function?**

```
app.factory('Pages', function($http, ENV){
    var Pages = {};

    Pages.details = 
    {
        pages: 
            {
                length: 0,
                offsets: []
            },
        ref:  
            {
            //data goes here on success
            },
        getPages: function($scope) {
            return $http.get(ENV.apiEndpoint + '/' + $scope.storeSlug + '/pages.json?code=' + $scope.promoCode)
            .success(function(data){
              // I want this Pages.details.ref to be replaced on success of getPages
              Pages.details.ref = data;
              $scope.handlePagesSuccess(data);

              return data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
              // console.log('error:' + status);
            });
        }
    }

    return Pages;
});
```

Controllers:
*this controller calls the init request*

```
app.controller('RandomCtrl', function($scope, Pages){
   var handleSuccess = function (data) {
      $scope.data = data;
   }
   Pages.details.getPages($scope).success(handleSuccess);
})
```

Controller #2:
*this controller just consumes a temp version of the request no relationship between the RandomCtrl.  e.g this controller is typically a directive level controller where the theres no bubbling between a parent ctrl*

```
app.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, Pages){
    $scope.tempPage = Pages.details.ref;
})
```

it shouldnt matter where getPages is called from.  I want ref to be replaced everytime getPages is called.

Comment: I promise I will but say tl:dr; is it possible? or am I f'd?

Comment: It's more of a scopeing issue I want a temp version of that data between parallel scopes.  I also want to append data to the object and share that between scopes. it's all scoping.

Comment: btw why are you using scope inside the factory? Factory consumer should ideally use promise pattern to get the data. I guess your actual issue could be somewhere else and you are probably trying to workaround by maintaining the state inside the factory?

Comment: I'll add the controller call too. Updated the code above.

Comment: I've added the code above to communicate the idea more. Sorry FOrmating

Comment: Thats correct and I dont want to use $watch from the init controller cuz it feels clumsy. and hard to read

Comment: Anyway that you could answer this for me cuz I have zero idea.  I'm so over my head right now but I feel like i'm stuck in scope hell.  I'm sinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59548/discussion-between-matthew-harwood-and-psl).

Comment: Hey man, I only pass back the data to the factory when the getPages has been called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to manage state inside your factory, which probably is not a good idea. Also it is not a good idea to pass around `$scope` in factories. They should be limited to its own controller. You could instead cache the promise for the previous call made and based on a flag you could either return the cached promise or make the actual service call.

```
app.factory('Pages', function($http, ENV, $q){
        var Pages = {};
        var cachedPromise = {};
        Pages.details = 
        {
            pages: 
                {
                    length: 0,
                    offsets: []
                },
            getPages: function(request) {
               //Get a request key to make sure you are returning right promise incase multiple product calls are made at the same time.
               var reqKey = request.storeSlug + request.promoCode;

               //if a call has already been made and there is a promise return it
               if(cachedPromise[reqKey]) return cachedPromise[reqKey];

               //Store the promise in the cache for lastCall retrieval
               return cachedPromise[reqKey] = $http.get(ENV.apiEndpoint + '/' + request.storeSlug + '/pages.json?code=' + request.promoCode)
                .then(function(result){
                    return result.data; //You can alter data and send as well
                }, function(data, status){
                    return $q.reject('some error'); //or return some data
                }).finally(function(){
                   //remove the cache from the map, once promise is resolved.
                   delete cachedPromise[reqKey];
               });

            }
        }
        return Pages;
    });
```

In your first controller do:-

```
app.controller('RandomCtrl', function($scope, Pages){
   //Build your request.
   Pages.details.getPages(request).then(function (data) {
       $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

In your second controller just do the same:-

```
app.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, Pages){
    //Pass the flag to get the cached data.
    Pages.details.getPages(request).then(function (data) {
       $scope.tempPage = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm reading up on the $q library but does this fire the getPages API request ? or it rejects it when cache is available.

Comment: It wont fire the request. If there is no last cache available the u will get undefined.

Comment: only part that feels weird is that we're forcing the getPages(true) in the OtherCtrl.  What if the RandomeCtrl and OtherCtrl fire at the same time?

Comment: Is there anyway that OtherCtrl can can fire the service also if OtherCtrl happens first? (i dont think this will happen but yeah...)

Comment: Exactly that is what I didnt know.what u are trying to do.

Comment: the OtherCtrl is a directive the RandomCtrl is like the MainCtrl.  This all happens at run time .. .depending on the routes.  So is there a better approch?